# addition in html using ruby on rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a table which has price and quantity fields. I want to add the price * quantity to the grand total for each item that i eventually add to the table.

My code looks like this.

```
<table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th width="200">Name</th>
            <th width="150">Price</th>
                      <th>Quantity</th>
                      <th width="150">Total</th>
                    </tr>
          <% @item.each do |item| %>
          <tr>
            <td><%= item.name %></td>
            <td><%= item.price %></td>
            <td><%= item.quantity %></td>
            <td><%= item.quantity * item.price %></td>
            <td class="actions">
              <% link_to("update", :class => 'action update') %>
              <% link_to("X", :class => 'action delete') %>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <% end %>
                </thead>
            </table>
```

and my grand total is in the form of a label.
how do i do this? Is there static variable concept in RoR??

Comment: Use database for these operations

Answer (score 2):

You should add the field grand_total in the table and create a callback in the Item model. This callback will save the value of grand total in the table each time a new item is created.

```
before_save : save_grand_total

def save_grand_total
  self.grand_total = self.quantity * self.price
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Enumerable#inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) to get the grand total as follows:

```
<% #= @item.inject{ |grand_total, quantity| grand_total + (quantity * cart.price) } %>
```

**Update:**

Please ignore the above line of code, that was to show you an example.  The following code example should solve your issue.

Place the following line where you'd like to display the grand total.

```
<%= label_tag 'grand_total', 
      @item.inject(0) { |grand_total, item| grand_total + (item.quantity * item.price) } %>
```

`@item.inject(0){ |grand_total, item| grand_total + (item.quantity * item.price) }` applies the block to each `item`.  The first parameter `grand_total` in this case is first assigned initial value of `0`.  This is done through `inject(0)`.

The block then starts accumulating `(item.quantity * item.price)` into `grand_total` which is the final value that is returned by the `inject`.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: @user3040563, seems the answerer has already provided sufficient code for you to go try this for yourself, no? It's pretty self explanatory, really...

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th width="200">Name</th>
        <th width="150">Price</th>
                  <th>Quantity</th>
                  <th width="150">Total</th>
                </tr>
     <% grand_total=0 %>
      <% @item.each do |item| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= item.name %></td>
        <td><%= item.price %></td>
        <td><%= item.quantity %></td>
        <td><%= item.quantity * item.price %></td>
        <% grand_total+= item.quantity * item.price %>
        <td class="actions">
          <% link_to("update", :class => 'action update') %>
          <% link_to("X", :class => 'action delete') %>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <% end %>
            </thead>
        </table>
```